# Transform Object into array containing the Object

Tags: jolt

I would like to wrap an object into an array using JoLT specification, for further use in NiFi.
But I cannot seem to get the solution.

Let's say I have this json as input

```
{
  "toIndex": [
    {
      "content": [
        {
          "firstName": "maxime",
          "lastName": "g",
          "toArray": {
            "one": "fun",
            "two": "funfun",
            "three": "funfunfun"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "content": [
        {
          "firstName": "monica",
          "lastName": "beluci",
          "toArray": {
            "one": "fun",
            "two": "funfun",
            "three": "funfunfun"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would very much like to get this as output :

```
{
  "toIndex": [
    {
      "content": [
        {
          "firstName": "maxime",
          "lastName": "g",
          "toArray": [ {
            "one": "fun",
            "two": "funfun",
            "three": "funfunfun"
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "content": [
        {
          "firstName": "monica",
          "lastName": "beluci",
          "toArray": [{
            "one": "fun",
            "two": "funfun",
            "three": "funfunfun"
          }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately I get this output :

```
{
  "toIndex" : [ {
    "content" : [ {
      "firstName" : "maxime",
      "lastName" : "g",
      "toArray" : {
        "one" : "fun",
        "two" : "funfun",
        "three" : "funfunfun"
      }
    }, {
      "toArray" : [ {
        "one" : "fun",
        "two" : "funfun",
        "three" : "funfunfun"
      } ]
    }, {
      "firstName" : "monica",
      "lastName" : "beluci",
      "toArray" : {
        "one" : "fun",
        "two" : "funfun",
        "three" : "funfunfun"
      }
    }, {
      "toArray" : [ {
        "one" : "fun",
        "two" : "funfun",
        "three" : "funfunfun"
      } ]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

My (miserable) spec goes like this :

```
[{
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "toIndex": {
        "*": {
          "content": {
            "*": {
              "@": "toIndex[&1].content[]", // passthru
              "toArray": "toIndex[&1].content[].toArray[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
]
```

If one of you be so kind as to indicate what I am doing wrong...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if the cardinality operation is what you are looking for:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "toIndex": {
        "*": {
          "content": {
            "*": {
              "toArray": "MANY"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output

```
{
  "toIndex" : [ {
    "content" : [ {
      "firstName" : "maxime",
      "lastName" : "g",
      "toArray" : [ {
        "one" : "fun",
        "two" : "funfun",
        "three" : "funfunfun"
      } ]
    } ]
  }, {
    "content" : [ {
      "firstName" : "monica",
      "lastName" : "beluci",
      "toArray" : [ {
        "one" : "fun",
        "two" : "funfun",
        "three" : "funfunfun"
      } ]
    } ]
  } ]
}
```